# Por que form.validate() me devuelve un objeto. JqueryValidate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Adjunto mi codigo Jquery que trabjo con la libreria JqueryValidate, en el condicional: **form.valid()** donde me  gustaria saber si el formulario es validado me devuelve un objeto: Aca les dejo el codigo:

```
$('#formvalidate').validate({
    rules: {
      //campos con validaciones
    },
    messages: {
     //mensajes
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element)
    {
      // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
      error.addClass("help-block");
      if (element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox")
      {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent("label") );
      }
      else
      {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      if($('input[name="tipobeca"]:checked').length == 0){
           alert('Por favor selecciona el tipo de beca');
           return false;
      }
      var form = $( "#formvalidate" );
      form.validate();
      console.log(form.validate());
      if ( form.valid() ){
              var action = $(this).attr('action');
              var method = $(this).attr('method');
              var data = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                url: action,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', true);
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Procesando...');
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                  if (!resp.success) {
                    swal({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: resp.message,
                            type: 'error'
                        });

                        $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', false);
                      $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Solicitar');
                  } else {
                    swal({
                            title: 'Mensaje',
                            text: resp.message,
                            type: 'success'
                        }).then(function() {
                          location.reload();
                        });
                  }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                        swal({
                          title: 'Error',
                          text: xhr.responseText,
                          type: 'error'
                      });

                  $('#btn-registro-beca').attr('disabled', false);
                  $('#btn-registro-beca').text('Solicitar');
                }
              });
              return false;
            }else{
              alert('Algunos campos son incorrectos');
              return false;
            }
        },
      

  });
```

EDIT: agrego el objeto que me imprime
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var form_count = 1, previous_form, next_form, total_forms;
  total_forms = $("fieldset").length;
  $(".next-form").click(function(){
    previous_form = $(this).parent();
    next_form = $(this).parent().next();
    next_form.show();
    previous_form.hide();
    setProgressBarValue(++form_count);
  });
  $(".previous-form").click(function(){
    previous_form = $(this).parent();
    next_form = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_form.show();
    previous_form.hide();
    setProgressBarValue(--form_count);
  });
  setProgressBarValue(form_count);
  function setProgressBarValue(value){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / total_forms) * value;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
    .css("width",percent+"%")
    .html(percent+"%");
  }
});
```

Comment: No entiendo por que usas `validate()` y `valid()` dentro del submitHandler de validate. La idea con validate es que la función `submitHandler` se lanza *solo si* el formulario es válido. En todo caso,  la [doc](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) es clara en cuanto al valor devuelto por `validate()`: un objeto tipo `validator`

Comment: Hola, Ok entendí. Pero, si yo quiero agregar otro boton externo (sacando el submit) y quiero que se ejecute solo si el formulario esta validado ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea con validate es que la función submitHandler se lanza solo si el formulario es válido. La [doc](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) es clara en cuanto al valor devuelto por validate(): un objeto tipo validator.

Para responder la otra pregunta en el comentario, luego de llamar el `validator`, puedes llamar `form.valid()` para verificar el formulario. Aqui hay un ejemplo de la documentacion de jQuery validate:

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
var form = $( "#myform" );
form.validate();
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if (form.valid()) {
  console.log('El formulario es valido, podemos enviarlo')
  } else {
  console.log('el formulario no es valido')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-37T7leoNS06R80c8Ulq7cdCDU5MNQBwlYoy1TX/WUsLFC2eYNqtKlV0QjH7r8JpG/S0GUMZwebnVFLPd6SU5yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="name" required>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Validar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente! Pero por que a mi siempre me devuelve True???? aunque no es asi, por que tengo en varios inputs datos incorrectos...

Comment: Si sigue devolviendo `true` con malos datos, algo en la validación no está bien configurado. Puedes usar la opción `debug: true` para evitar enviar el formulario y revisar los datos y las reglas.

Comment: el debug:true lo unico que me hizo corregir fue que algunos checkbox no tenian la propiedad name="" pero nada mas, esto me esta matando la capocha ja

Comment: Ya descubri el error

Comment: Estoy diviendo el formulario en 3 <fieldset>.

Comment: La cual con el script que adjunte ahora en la publicacion, lo divido en 3 pasos.

Comment: Hasta aca funciona perfecto, lo que me hace romper el codigo es el siguiente css:

Comment: #formvalidate fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
  }

Comment: Como puedo solucionarlo?????

Comment: Prueba usar `position: absolute; visibility: hidden` en vez de `display: none`

Comment: ok pruebo! gracias

Comment: No, no funciona, cree otra pregunta aparte...

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492138/como-validar-inputs-que-estan-en-otro-fieldset-con-la-propiedad-displaynone